# How do I tell Rails inmemory cache not to create an entry if the value is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, null, ruby-on-rails-5, in-memory

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to use Rails in-memory store cache to cache data, however, I would not like to cache such data if the value of the data is nil.  How do I do this?  I thoguth I coudl extend Rails cache and write my own method, so I found the below code

```
module ActiveSupport
 module Cache
    class Store
      def fetch_no_nil(name, options = nil)
        if block_given?
          options = merged_options(options)
          key = namespaced_key(name, options)

          cached_entry = find_cached_entry(key, name, options) unless options[:force]
          entry = handle_expired_entry(cached_entry, key, options)

          if entry
            get_entry_value(entry, name, options)
          else
            save_block_result_to_cache_if_not_nil(name, options) { |_name| yield _name }
          end
        else
          read(name, options)
        end
      end
      private
      def save_block_result_to_cache_if_not_nil(name, options)
        result = instrument(:generate, name, options) do |payload|
          yield(name)
        end
        write(name, result, options) unless result.nil?
        result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

however, this doesn't appear to work on Raisl 5.  I get the below error when I invoke the "fetch_no_nil" method ...

```
Please use `normalize_key` which will return a fully resolved key.
 (called from fetch_no_nil at /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/initializers/enhanced_cache.rb:7)
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_cached_entry' for #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore:0x007fa6b92ae088>
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/initializers/enhanced_cache.rb:9:in `fetch_no_nil'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:116:in `get_cached_content'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:73:in `get_url'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Is there another way I can instruct my Rails cache not to create an entry if the value is nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't monkeypatch `ActiveSupport::Cache`. Just write a wrapper method:

```
def self.cache_unless_nil(key, value)
  Rails.cache.fetch(key) { value } unless value.nil?
end
```

Then cache objects by calling your wrapper:

```
cache_unless_nil("foo", "bar")
Rails.cache.fetch("foo")
#=> "bar"
cache_unless_nil("baz", nil)
Rails.cache.fetch("baz")
#=> nil
```